# What's wrong with this route

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api-routing

Given the following:

```
namespace Foo.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/route")]
    public class SnoconesFooBarController : BaseApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Asks for a new foo to be created to the given subnet with the specific bar named
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fooName"></param>
        /// <param name="uriString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("newFoo/{fooName}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostNewFooForSpecificBar(string fooName, string uriString)
        {
        }
}
```

Why do I get a 404 when I try to post to:

http://localhost:4471/api/route/newFoo/test1

with the following payload:

"http://127.0.0.1"

Comment: This is a route for what framework (API/MVC etc)..

Comment: MVC, and I changed the question to be more refined @ErikPhilips

Comment: does it matter that your variable name is `sourceName` and not `fooName`?

Comment: This appears to be an APIController in a MVC Project.

Comment: @ErikPhilips It works just fine for all of my other routes.

Comment: @RufusL That's an artifact of me trying to make it less obvious what my method is doing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I fixed it by changing it to look like this:

```
 namespace Foo.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/route")]
    public class SnoconesFooBarController : BaseApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Asks for a new foo to be created to the given subnet with the specific bar named
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fooData"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("newFoo/")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostNewFooForSpecificBar(FooRequestObject fooData)
        {
        }
}
```

And including all of the data I needed in the FooRequestObject